# How to print a winforms usercontrol

Tags: c#, printing, user-controls

I've created a winforms usercontrol doing a lot of custom painting in the OnPaint event. Now I would like to print this control.

- is there a wysiwyg method to position this control on 'a document' and print the document including the usercontrol ?

or

- when using printpage() event of a printdocument, can I dynamically create & position my usercontrol on the 'page' and somehow call the paint method of my usercontrol ?

Comment: is it a wpf/xaml usercontrol?

Comment: Lots of report designer products around, none that know anything about your user control.  The simple way is to expose a method that takes a Graphics object, move your painting code into that method.  Now you can call it both from your OnPaint() method *and* your PrintPage event handler, passing e.Graphics in both.  Use Graphics.TranslateTransform() in your PrintPage event handler to move it anywhere you want it on the page.  Perhaps ScaleTransform() if you need it bigger or smaller.

Comment: OK, thank you Hans, that is what I was planning to do. I was just hoping for some kind of framework/printengine that is capable of handling user controls

Answer (score 0):

In PrintPage event aquire image of control, and draw it to printer graphics.

```
private void PrintPageEventHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev) {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, yourControl.Width, yourControl.Height);

            //aquire image of yourControl
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(yourControl.Width, yourControl.Height);     
            yourControl.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, rect);

            ev.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(0, 0)); //place image on right position istead of (0, 0)

}
```

Comment: Never *ever* do this, a printer has a much higher resolution than the screen.  Those pixels in the bitmap turn into 6x6 blobs of ink on paper.  That only ever looks good when you grow longer arms.